# Deploy the same cloud service to different VMs

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I got a cloud service (worker role) which I want to deploy to a beta and a production environment.

It seems a waste to have to create three projects (one with the actual implementation and two for deployment).

Is it possible to create two deployment profiles which links to different Azure destinations but uses the same worker role project?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do. Just build your Azure package without deploying, and keep your dev/beta/prod settings in the Service Configuration, not embedded anywhere like `web.config`/`app.config`. Then store both the deployment package and configuration in blob storage (speeding up deployment). You'll want multiple configuration files: one for each environment, each stored separately in blob storage.

Once this is done, you can just deploy the package to multiple cloud services, each with a different configuration file. This can be done either through the portal or through PowerShell / CLI.

If you've been deploying directly from Visual Studio, it might not seem quite as obvious. But from VS, you can build a package without actually deploying.